# Postgres database does not have all the tables needed for OSM

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I installed Postgres/Postgis for mac osx. I followed all the steps needed to import osm data into the database as required (this includes setting up a user, a database and having spherical mercator projection done) but for some reason, the tables planet_osm_line, planet_osm_roads, planet_osm_polygon, etc are not even showing up in the database I created. Following is the success message for importing osm data in the database:

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=102400*8192, allocation method=3
Mid: Ram, scale=100

Reading in file: map.osm
Processing: Node(0k 0.9k/s) Way(0k 0.09k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)  parse time: 0s

Node stats: total(923), max(3044483353) in 0s
Way stats: total(86), max(291932583) in 0s
Relation stats: total(0), max(0) in 0s
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads

...
```

Creating indexes on  planet_osm_roads finished
   All indexes on  planet_osm_roads created  in 0s
   Completed planet_osm_roads

Osm2pgsql took 0s overall

I followed the steps listed here: http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/20/how-to-import-open-street-map-data-into-postgresql/

and here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GpsDrive

but still the relations above do not show up. I just get an error saying such relations do not exist when I query my database. What else am I missing here?

Comment: Where did your `map.osm` come from? Does it include relations?

Comment: i downloaded it from openstreetmap.org. Just now It has node id, timestamp, user, latitute and longitude. How to I get relations in the xml file? Do I have to download it from a different source like planet-osm? How do I download this for a small area?

Comment: You don't need a different source. But you need a relation in the area you downloaded and obviously the area you chose didn't contain any relation.

Comment: This time i downloaded a larger area, from https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/ Any idea as to why the relations are not getting added?

Comment: Have you verified whether the new file contains relations?

Comment: Actually it does.Something like this: <relation id="335071" visible="true" version="50" changeset="26015899" timestamp="2014-10-12T00:04:00Z" user="n76" uid="318696">

Comment: I was so dumb to be in the current db and check for these relations... I now changed to the db i created and found those. It is working now. Thanks!